# How to make a textarea ouput textarea code without breaking?

Tags: php, html

I created a form where users can enter html code and it outputs their code in another textarea.  The problem is that if the html the user enters has a textarea in the code, the  in their code breaks my textarea form.  I see other sites display any html correctly so how is this done without breaking the form and allowing the user to copy it so that it still remains as   and not some converted code so they can paste it on their webpage?

Ah crap yeah I figured it out, in fact the problem wasn't with the htmlspecialchars code alone I forgot to add a return to one of my functions haha.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Represent characters that have special meaning in HTML using entities. Since you are using PHP, use [htmlspecialchars](http://uk.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: You may also want to use "htmlentities", which is like a souped-up "htmlspecialchars".

Comment: Just watch out for `&amp;amp;` with these though (unless you're running 5.3x with the double encode boolean flag).

Comment: @Ayman "bloated" you wanted to say? any reason one want to use this pointless function?

Comment: @Ayman there wasn't actually point in my question, here it is: htmlentities will change all foreaign characters to entities, while it's wrong and unnecessary. Just set proper encoding for the page and you will need no entity. For the rest htmlspecialchars is enough

Answer (score 0):

There are millions and millions of ways to do this.  The easiest is to use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` on the user's input.  This will make a visual `</textarea>` in the textarea box without closing it.  This actually turns it into `&lt;/textarea&gt;`.  `htmlspecialchars` transforms less characters than `htmlentities` and usually makes more sense to use in a situation like this, but do your research.

`strip_tags()` is also a possibility.

You can also use a regular expression with PCRE, or even str_replace() or other string manipulation functions to strip off the textarea, convert the special characters, etc.

PECL also as a BB code extension you can use if you still want your users to be able to enter some for of tags to style their output.

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($code); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to transform the html code into symbols, so it is not treated as html.

Use the function `htmlentities()` on the textarea content before echoing it.